# Slide show using ViewFlipper and Webview android

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a 3 WebView Inner ViewFlipper, slide interval is 5 second.
first image is show clearly, but in second and other image not show and always return to first image.
how to make it very simply perfect load and sliding.
this my code

```
//first time load URL to Webview
    wv1.loadUrl("image1");
    wv2.loadUrl("image2");
    wv3.loadUrl("image3");
```

and I try to start slide it

```
// start to slide with interval 5s
    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipview);

    if(mFlipping==0){
        /** Start Flipping */
        flipper.startFlipping();
        mFlipping=1;
    }
    else{
        /** Stop Flipping */
        flipper.stopFlipping();
        mFlipping=0;
    }
```

help me to fix it,, I want to slide from URL

Comment: Better option is to use `ViewPager`.

Comment: i think even I use ViewPager the same problem will appear about load image from URL. have u ever use WebView inner ViewPager and how about every slide that call URL to show it image?